# Capture local http post traffic

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler, wireshark

I have two C# winform applications on the same window machine.

- First application runs a http listener on localhost and port 4567
  (not via IIS)
- Second application issue a http post (httpWebRequest)
  to port 4567.

I'm trying to see the post/request traffic like I normally would when viewing http traffic in Fiddler2.  I have no luck so far when trying to capture this traffic with fiddler2, Charles and Wireshark.

Does anyone have insight on how to capture this traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the requests to your localhost application using fiddler, please set the URL in the calling application as shown below

http://localhost.fiddler:4567/

The following post should help you out

[Monitor traffic to localhost from IE or .NET](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic)

Answer (score 1):

Fiddler cannot intercept localhost traffic, because fiddler is a proxy server, and local requests are not sent through proxy server by the .NET Framework.

To work around this, you can update your applications to send data to `localhost.fiddler` instead of `localhost`